# Adding Anaconda to Path or not

Tags: python, windows, path, anaconda, environment

The official recommendation is not to add Anaconda / Python to the Windows `PATH` environment variable (see [Anaconda User Guide FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq)). But how can I ensure then that my custom build scripts find python? (e.g. my `sphinx` `make.bat`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Current Anaconda installations offer an "Anaconda Prompt" that has `conda` on the path. Go to the Windows start button (Window icon) and start typing `anaconda`.  You should see an entry "Anaconda Prompt". Click on it. A new window opens that has `conda` in the search path. Use as many Anaconda prompts as needed.

**Old Answer**

A good way is to work with `conda` environments.

1. Add the path where the `conda.exe` to the `PATH` temporally:

   `set PATH=C:\my\path\to\conda;%PATH%`
2. Create a new environment:

   `conda create -n py36 python=3.6`
3. Activate it:

   `activate py36`

Now the prompt should change to `py36` and all should work since all needed paths are set. You need to install all your packages you need for your project while this environment is activated. When done deactivate it with `deactivate`.

Comment: but should I endure this pain every time I want a quick python/ipython/jupyter session? Any suggestions on making this more practical?

Comment: Once you created the environment, you can write a file `myenv.bat` with this content: `set PATH=C:\my\path\to\conda;%PATH% & activate py36` and activate your environment with `myenv`.

Comment: I still don't really get why having conda on the path is such a bad thing. I suppose if you've got various different versions of conda for whatever nefarious reason, but is that the dominant case?

Comment: There is no problem with `conda`. But it also puts `python` on the `PATH`. This might interfere with other installed programs that use a different, already installed Python version.

Comment: If you install the "console_shortcut" package, you get a start menu entry that is a shortcut to drop you into an activated shell.  You get one shortcut for each environment that you install "console_shortcut" into.

Comment: I still maintain it's more of a pain to not have it on the path and have to either use the "special" anaconda prompt or keep adding it to the path manually. That and having user specific paths means that a team wide script to set up a prefix virtualenv for a project is impractical, as everyone's conda install location may be different. If there's a way around that particular use case, then maybe I can get over having commands usefully on the path

Comment: @CraigBrett Indeed there is a better way now. Updated my answer.