# Add conda to my environment variables or path?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, anaconda

I am having trouble adding conda to my environment variables on windows. **I installed anaconda 3** though **I didn't installed python**, so **neither** **pip** or **pip3 is working** in my prompt. I viewed a few post online but I didn't find anything regarding how to add conda to my environment variables.

I tried to create a PYTHONPATH variable which contained **every single folder** in **Anaconda 3** though it didn't worked.

My **anaconda prompt isn't working** too. :(

so...How do I add **conda** and **pip** to my environment variables or path ?

Comment: What do you mean by _My anaconda prompt isn't working too_ ? That might be showing a reinstall is needed. By the way, isn't there a checkbox when installing anaconda to add it to your path ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access to conda and pip directly in their directory :

- On **Windows** : %ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR%\Scripts, you will find conda.exe and pip.exe
- On **Linux** : $ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR/bin, there are conda and pip executable files.

Where $ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR is the directory of your Anaconda installation.

To add Anaconda to your path, you can add this folder to your PATH.
For **Linux**, you can add this line to yout .bashrc file

```
export PATH=$ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR/bin:$PATH
```

As said @BcK, reinstalling Anaconda and choosing to add Anaconda to your path is also a way to do this. This option makes a backup of your .bashrc file and add the export line.

**EDIT**

To open a terminal with the conda environment activated on **Windows**, I usually create a desktop shortcut with the following target :

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" %ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR%\Scripts\activate.bat %ANACONDA_INSTALL_DIR%
```

Comment: I think the "$" is unnecessary for Windows 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185057/adding-anaconda-to-path-or-not

Comment: This worked for me make sure you add to the PATH for system environment variables and then when you try to conda activate base in cmd.exe, it'll tell you to cmd init cmd.exe, close that shell and reopoen it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for helping me out. I solved the problem reinstalling anaconda (several times :[ ), cleaning every log and resetting the path variables via `set path=` in the windows power shell (since I got some problems reinstalling anaconda adding the folder to PATH[specifically "unable to load menus" or something like that])

Answer (score 0):

The path where Anaconda3 is present on your windows system will not work. C:\Users\pcuser\Anaconda3

Try this:
Open conda prompt and the following

```
conda list
```

gives the list of packages. try uninstalling any one package

```
conda uninstall <any package>
```

It will prompt the package path where the package is installed. It will look something like this:

c:\users\appdata\local\anaconda3\scripts\

Add this path to my PATH environment-variable. It works from git bash or cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is appropriate in the 'Answers' section (since for me it is a question as much as an answer). But for Windows OS, upon installing Anaconda (or in my case, miniconda) it *specifically* says that adding to the PATH variable is NOT recommended (version 23.9, installed in Nov 2023).

[image: Not recommended to]

For this reason, I have been holding off doing so and trying to use the custom Anaconda PowerShell Prompt which comes included in the install. However I am not sure how necessary this caution is. Does anyone else know any further info on this?